# Is there any way to make this more efficient/reduce the amount of loops?

Tags: java

Given an int n, print a staircase using #. This is from hacker rank, staircase problem. example:
n = 4.

output:

```
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

whereas each row has the same amount of columns but the # signs increase and the space decrease as we keep going through the rows.

I've solved the problem, just trying to see if there is a more efficient way

```
public static void staircase(int n) {
    int spaceCounter = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // Takes care of the rows
        spaceCounter = n - i;

        // Takes care of the column by printing a space until a # sign is required then it would print so.
        for (int j = 1; j <= spaceCounter; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");

            if (j == spaceCounter) {
                //Prints as many #s as needed (n minus the number of spaces needed)
                for(int k = 1; k <= (n - spaceCounter); k++) {
                    System.out.print("#");
                }

               //makes sure it goes to the next life after being done with each row
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        if (i == n) {
            for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com. We're about fixing broken code here.

Comment: As your code currently works I believe it belongs to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (The link points to their How to ask).

Comment: Sorry, kind of new here but thank you, now i know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Java 11, you can utilize [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) for an efficient solution that uses a single for-loop:

```
public static void staircase(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(n - i) + "#".repeat(i));
    }
}
```

All we do is calculate the amount of spaces that are needed for the specific *line*, and then the number of `#` characters needed is simply `n` minus the amount of spaces used.

---

If `n` is a large value, you can build a `String` (using a `StringBuilder`) and then print it instead of calling `System.out.println` `n` times:

```
public static void staircase(int n) {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sb.append(" ".repeat(n - i)).append("#".repeat(i)).append('\n');
    }

    System.out.print(sb);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `deleteCharAt` you could just use `print` instead of `println`. If you assume that `println` flushes the buffer (which it usually does) call `flush` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! repeat and string builder are still new to me but i can understand how they work.

Comment: Also, if we are talking about a really *efficient* solution wouldn't it be better to have two StringBuilders? One filled with spaces that gets shorter in each iteration and one filled with `#` that gets longer in each iteration so that we don't have to call `repeat` so often.